# Rename layer in gpkg using QGIS or PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

I have a gpkg of several layers. How can I rename them in the gpkg as well as in the QGIS layers list?

Basically, I have layer `foo` in my QGIS project, whose source is `filename.gpkg|layername=foo`. I now want to call it `bar`.

It's easy (rightclick, rename) to change `foo` to `bar` *in the QGIS project layer list*. But it's still called `foo` *inside the gpkg*. I can't rename it inside the gpkg from the GeoPackage connection inside the QGIS browser: it lets me rightclick and choose rename, but OK is greyed out (presumably since it's in use).

As a workaround, I can rename it `bar` in the QGIS project layer list, export it from the QGIS project layer to a temporary gpkg (where it becomes named `bar` and `foo` is forgotten), import it from there as a duplicate to the right gpkg, use the `changeDataSource` plugin to point the project layer to the new name, and then clean up by deleting the old `foo` in the gpkg. And eventually vacuum the db.

But that's a hassle given I've set up a naming convention to use across projects, and now need to rename 20+ layers across several gpkg to reflect it (and so I and others can re-use those gpkgs in other projects).

Answer (score 11):

You can rename the tables in GeoPackage with the DB Manager

[image]

Another option is to use ogrinfo with the OGR SQL dialect as documented in https://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html. Usage:

```
ogrinfo my_geopackage.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE layer_name RENAME TO new_layer"
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks. The DB Manager approach, however, unloads the layer from the current project so you have to manually re-add it (and hopefully you saved the style...). Good find on the `orginfo` (would still need to use changeDataSource, of course); I didn't think of using a `-sql` but am reassured from those docs that 'Starting with GDAL 2.2, the "DROP TABLE layer_name" and "ALTER TABLE layer_name RENAME TO new_layer" statements can be used. They will update GeoPackage system tables.'

Comment: Renaming the table is not a simple task because the corresponding table that holds the spatial index must be renamed as well, a bunch of database triggers must be deleted and created again, and records in the geopackage metadata tables must be updated.