# Using QGIS Table Manager?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table

in QGIS 2.18 I used the table manager plugin for renaming or removing columns in a table. This plugin doesn´t exist in QGIS 3.4.1.

Is there any other plugin or way to rename, remove or order columns in the attribute table of a vector layer?

Comment: For the database layers you can use the DB Manager, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315132/rename-layer-in-gpkg-using-qgis-or-pyqgis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the Refactor Fields tool in the processing toolbox.

You can rename, reorder, and change the types of the fields. You can also import fields from other layers and map the old fields to the new fields.

It creates a new layer but if you want you can just save over the original.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to save over the original directly in the refactor fields tool? I export the virtual layer and save it over the original file. Then I reload the original file and then I can see the changes.

Comment: @joe_gerner - Not from within the tool. And it can be bad practice to do that anyway as you may lose a lot of the original data if it doesn't work as intended. The safer option is to create a new file and then change the source of the layers in your project so they point at the new file instead of the original (which you should keep at least for a while until you are sure you don't need it).

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way is to edit via DB Manager (if the layer is in a geopackage for example).

1. Make a connection to the database via DB Manager
2. Click on the layer within the database
3. In the top menu, click on Table/Edit Table.
4. Under columns, edit the appropriate column/field. (you can also change the type of field if required)
5. Save