# How to batch rename tables in GeoPackage with OGR

Tags: ogr, geopackage, ogrinfo

I would like to rename all tables in a GeoPackage file. The "translations" are stored in a .csv file.

I would like to do this on the command line and found the below thread that uses the following command:

```
ogrinfo my_geopackage.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE old_layer_name RENAME TO new_layer_name"
```

(from: [Rename layer in gpkg using QGIS or PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315132/rename-layer-in-gpkg-using-qgis-or-pyqgis))

How do I modify the above so that old_layer_name and new_layer_name are fetched from the .csv file? Keep in mind that I am a noob.

Comment: It could be faster to create a new GeoPackage with ogr2ogr and rename the layers by using the `-nln` parameters.

Comment: What is not clear with ogr command in the question? It works. You need to repeat it for each tables you have in your gpkg

Comment: `ogrinfo "PATH_TO_YOUR_GPKG" -sql "ALTER TABLE NAME_OF_THE_TABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_RENAME RENAME TO NEW_NAME`
Here you have to first give the path to your gpkg and then write the name of your table and the target name

Comment: Please note that I want to change the names in a batch by referencing a -csv file. I know how to change the names of single layers. But need help on how to change hundreds of table names in one run.

Comment: What command line have you got? A unix-y shell, like bash, or Windows CMD, or something else? You could write a program in almost any language to do read a CSV and run the commands or simply output them - python, R, perl... what are you skilled at?

Comment: Saying "Keep in mind that I am a noob." doesn't help - tell us what you *do* know how to do, and what your skills are, and not only does that help its also a good positive statement about yourself. Suppose you are good at spreadsheets, you could load the CSV into a spreadsheet and create a new column with the ogr2ogr command, save that column, run it as a script...

Comment: I would be running it from MacOS Terminal. I have no programming background. Often I manage to patch something together by combining a couple of scripts I found on google. This time I am stuck on how to call the .csv file. Maybe that should have been the headline. I would prefer to build a reusable script rather than the extra step with spreadsheets.

Comment: There are some fairly low-level command-line tools - `awk` immediately springs to mind - that can read input files - including CSVs - and do stuff with them. This is a good point at which to *get* some programming background though!

Comment: Example, this `awk` one liner, fed a CSV file of `oldname,newname` pairs, will print out `awk -F, '{printf("ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql \"ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s\"\n",$1,$2) }' < rename.csv` will print one `ogr2ogr` command for each line. I'll put this in as answer if the question gets out of "off-topic jail".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using the `awk` utility to read the CSV and create the commands. Given a CSV like:

```
foo,bar
baz,qux
quux,quuux
this,that
me,you
same,same
```

Then this command line:

```
awk -F, '{printf("ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql \"ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s\"\n",$1,$2) }' < rename.csv
```

will print out the following commands:

```
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO bar"
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE baz RENAME TO qux"
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE quux RENAME TO quuux"
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE this RENAME TO that"
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE me RENAME TO you"
ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql "ALTER TABLE same RENAME TO same"
```

`awk` has a `system` function that can run things within an `awk` line, but I often prefer to send the commands to a file, use `chmod` to make it executable,  and run that:

```
awk -F, '{printf("ogrinfo my.gpkg -sql \"ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s\"\n",$1,$2) }' < rename.csv  > renamer.sh
chmod 755 renamer.sh
./renamer.sh
```